# How can I add variables from a preprocessor function to be used in an unformatted view template?

Tags: views, theming

The variables I'm adding in my preprocessor function are not visible in the template for the *unformatted* view I've written. This seems to work fine if the template is formatted (the default).

That is, in template.php I set some variable `$foo` in the preprocessor…

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  // Do view-specific preprocessing in here because of http://drupal.org/node/939462
  if ( $vars['view']->name === "viewname" ) {
    $vars['foo'] = 'bar'; // set $foo to be used in viewname templates
  }
}
```

…such that I can use it in views-view--viewname.tpl.php, `<?php echo $foo; ?>`. This works just fine.

However, **`$foo` is undefined in views-view-*unformatted*--viewname.tpl.php**.

Why is this? How can I store the results of my preprocessing in a variable I can then use in the template for my *unformatted* view?

Doing the preprocessing in a function specific to the unformatted view doesn't work because

- such a function, `themename_preprocess_views_view_unformatted__viewname()`, will not be called [due to a bug](http://drupal.org/node/939462), and
- working around the bug by defining its behaviour in, or calling it from, `themename_preprocess_views_view()` doesn't work

  - as above, where I seem to make changes to `$vars` that should be accessible in all viewname view templates,
  - nor can it be repeated specifically for the unformatted view templates because there's nothing in `$vars` that can be used to discriminate the unformatted from the default view.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the output for the view is built up from the inside-out.  So, the views-view template already has the processed results from the views-view-unformatted template.

You should just be able to implement a [`template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted/7), and do a manual check:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];

  if ($view->name == 'viewname') {
    $variables['foo'] = 'bar';
  }
}
```

I don't typically use unformatted output, but I do it somewhat often at the field level.

Comment: Took me a looooooong time to figure this out. Is there a part of the documentation somewhere that explains hierarchy of how views are "built up from the inside out"?