# Retrieve node information in VIEWS template(s)

Tags: views, theming

I have figured out I need to override two templates:

1. views-view-fields.tpl.php
2. views-view-unformatted.tpl.php

Basically my node has an "align" property which I need to access in both templates to properly generate the expected markup.

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_defined_vars()); exit; ?>
```

Using this I can see I have a monster of a structure at my disposal but the I am nervous about traversing such a structure as the slightest change to it's arrangment means my template(s) would break!!!

Ideally I would like to implement a preprocessor such as:

[How can I add variables from a preprocessor function to be used in an unformatted view template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65542/how-can-i-add-variables-from-a-preprocessor-function-to-be-used-in-an-unformatte)

Basically add the "align" value from the node to a simple variable which I can then access and check inside both templates listed above...

Suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`to find out which hook you have to react on, in your case it should be `hook_preprocess_views_view_fields()` and `hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()`.

Next you have to find a way to access the node object. If your view is node based, then there should be an nid somewhere in the variables array. Don't be afraid to dif into the `$variables` array. You can use dpm (devel module) or `print_r`or whatever you're comfortable with. You can't really break anything without manipulating the array.

Comment: but if a module changes the structure of the array:

$row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_align['und'][0]['value']

is what I currently have it is so deeply nested that the slightest change would break...no fear you say, eh? :)

Comment: You should of course prepare for the case that the expected data is not there, using `isset()`will do. Where does `$row->_field_data` come from? That's in `$variables`?

Comment: not variables no sorry (views-view-fields.tpl.php)